# sfPHPCaptchaPlugin : The following code is invalid

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4

I meet a very strange problem,I used sfPHPCaptchaPlugin to make captha to my form in sf1.4 project I worked on,all configuration and installation of plugin is correct but the captcha verification won't let me save data of form in database and tell me that the text is wrong but I'm sure I entered the same text showing in image of captcha and here is the line who get me the error :

```
'captcha'       => new sfValidatorPHPCaptcha(array(), array('invalid' => 'The following code is invalid.')),
```

Someone had the same errore before please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sfPHPCaptchaPlugin is not stable for symfony 1.4 as it said in the plugin information [Here](http://www.symfony-project.org/plugins/sfPHPCaptchaPlugin).

You can use [sfCaptchaGDPlugin](http://www.symfony-project.org/plugins/sfCaptchaGDPlugin) its a very good one, folow the intalation guide in README, and use this widget:

```
$this->widgetSchema['captcha'] = new sfWidgetCaptchaGD();

$this->validatorSchema['captcha'] = new sfCaptchaGDValidator(array('length' => 4));
```